# Why can't non-horse creatures be registered?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Breath of the Wild, you can ride several non-horse creatures, but you can't register them, why can't you, and why is the Lord of the Mountain considered non-horse.

Answer (score 3):

Stables can only board living horses, the reason might be that they aren't fit to accommodate other animals, such as bears and deer.

As for the Lord of the Mountain, it is a spirit of a beast, and Embry from Breath of the Wild implies it's a bad omen to have it around:

[image: Registering Lord of the Mountain]

Even if you could register it, the Lord of the Mountain disappears shortly after you dismount it.